# SSI navigation bar, highlight selected option

Tags: javascript, css, ssi

I have a navigation bar that I include using SSI in every page of a small site. Something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="option1.shtml">option 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="option2.shtml">option 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="option3.shtml">option 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

In each page I want to highlight the selected option (maybe with bold) and disable the "self" link.

As I'm not using any Server Side technology as PHP or .NET, I think this could be achieve using JavaScript.

Many thanks.

Comment: Typically, you would not ask this community to write something for you from scratch.  After you make a serious attempt at programming this for yourself, you'd ask a specific question if you get stuck.  (Yes, you'd do this with JavaScript.)

Comment: Thanks, I was not expecting anybody to write my code, I just wanted to know if there was another option apart from javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's interesting about the example that you list is that the options are actually links!  Are the links handled in Javascript?  This is somewhat important to determine the answer to the question, so my answer will inherently be a bit general.

The following method I'm describing assumes that there are `a` tags with `href` attributes in the list items.

First use `document.URL` to grab the current page's URL.  Store that in a variable `url`.  Then use `url.substr(url.search('www.beginning.com/of/URL/before/links/start/'))` to get the part of the URL that would be in the link-, e.g. `index.html`.  Finally, find the link with `href="index.html"` and use `removeAttribute("href")` to remove its href attribute.  In addition add a class called `thisPage` to the element so that in CSS you can highlight it and remove the pointer cursor:

```
.thisPage
{
    cursor: default;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Please tell me if this was helpful and whether you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to add a <a> tag inside each <li> tag! :)

I think your solution is easy and clear :)